# Vue3 Transition not working for Router-Link within Route

Tags: vuejs3, css-transitions, vue-router

The other day I was trying to setup a vue-router page. The basic idea is that you have on each route a button to go to another one. I tried to animate those with simple fade transitions and while the content of the routes faded properly the vue-router-links just appeared and disappeared. Am I missing something?